# Como utilizar senhas com segurança dentro de uma aplicação Android?

Tags: php, android, api, webserver

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android onde preciso autenticar o usuário do app e retornar algumas informações, mas estas informaçãos ficarão em um banco de dados remoto (MySQL), então para isso desenvolvi uma API que recebe um valor GET ou POST com uma string criptografada e retorna os valores do usuário, neste caso estou utilizando criptografia AES que precisa de uma Chave para criptografia e descriptografia.

Minha preocupação é: como utilizar essa chave `static String AESKey` para criptografia AES dentro da aplicação android sem correr o risco que a aplicação seja quebrada e a chave visualizada?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Um aplicativo Android e feito em Java. Então, quebrar e facil. 2 opçoes:
1) criar um pedaço de codigo em ARM
2) guardar a chave do lado PHP. Então, vc quere se conectar? OK, o PHP vai enviar um SMS para vc, com a chave e vc vai digitar a chave no Android, chave que vai ser reconhecida durante (por exmplo.) 10 minutos.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o propósito da chave, nem do processo de cifragem. Sua preocupação é com a segurança da comunicação? (use SSL) Ou é em autenticar o usuário, i.e. cada usuário terá uma chave distinta? (guarde essa chave na pasta privada do app) Ou outra coisa? Criptografia simétrica sozinha não serve pra muita coisa, então sugiro rever seu design. Se explicar melhor qual é a sua preocupação principal posso dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Minha necessidade é desenvolver um aplicativo que se conecte a uma DB remota, que faz parte de um site de guia de turismo, neste aplicativo eu preciso que o usuário faça o login utilizando os mesmos dados do site. Então pensei em desenvolver a API para que o APP fizesse a requisição e API retornasse os valores do usuário por JSON, e para isso pensei em gerar uma string em base64 ou AES, o problema disso é que como não existe um token ou algo do tipo, qualquer usuário pode chegar na API e fazer alguma requisição através de GET ou POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de responder à pergunta colocada é:

**Não guarde a sua password no código, pois ela será facilmente lida.**

Claro que uma solução para a sua pergunta depende muito também do serviço ao qual a sua aplicação se está a ligar... mas partindo do ponto que tem acesso à aplicação e ao servidor...

O caminho que está a querer seguir além de ir precisar de criptografia, irá claramente precisar de trabalhar com certificados, etc. Proteger a sua password é o menores dos problemas que irá enfrentar nesta jornada, onde a regra de ouro é ... nunca, mas nunca guardar uma password no código quando a segurança da mesma é um requisito.

Dito isto, quero indicar que por experiência, o nível de segurança que irá certamente implementar, estará proporcionalmente ligada à importância que o mercado/utilizadores colocam na sua aplicação. Isto porque para qualquer um de nós que criamos aplicações a importância sobre a nossa criação é sempre máxima.

No entanto esquecemos muitas vezes de olhar para a realidade da mesma.

Percebendo eu que procura uma resposta técnica para este problema e de forma a poder melhor ajudar nesta questão e dentro do que está a implementar... indico várias soluções... mas todas muito questionáveis no que respeita a segurança:

1. Ofuscar código
2. tornar a password o mais aleatória possível
3. utilizar algoritmos fortes

etc, etc..etc.

Olhando para o seu trecho de código e percebendo que precisa de gerir uma password que irá ser utilizada na comunicação entre dois pontos de forma a ser o mais confidencial possível... e partindo do pressuposto que a password pode ser dinâmica, e não imposta pelo servidor onde se liga e se a despesa em SSL não for do seu melhor interesse então porque não utilizar o algoritmo de **Diffie-Helman**. Ou seja, através do modelo matemático é possível dois pontos acordarem numa chave a cada nova conexão.

Desta forma nunca mais irá precisar de guardar passwords. Aviso: este algoritmo é permissível a ataques man-in-the-middle... e por isso uma vez mais ... o SSL é obrigatório.